# Rails 3: Can't Mass Assign Nested Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm getting the infamous error:

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: comments
```

As far as I can tell, I've done everything right in my model:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :author, :edition, :issue, :title, :url, :comments_attributes
  has_many :comments, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :comments, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

And view:

```
<%= form_for @book, :remote => true do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>:
  <%= f.text_field :title %><br />

  <%= f.label :author %>:
  <%= f.text_field :author %><br />

  <%= f.fields_for @comment do |comment| %>
  <%= comment.label :body, :Comment %>:
  <%= comment.text_area :body %><br />
  <% end %>

  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

What am I missing here? I've read through over a dozen similar questions on stackoverflow, but the only advice out there seems to be to add attr_accessible and accepts_nested_attributes_for, both of which I've already got. Surely there's something else?

Comment: In a desperate attempt, I'd try to put the `has_many` declaration on top, before the attr_accessible declaration ...

Comment: Interesting idea, but unfortunately, still no luck.

Comment: In the Comment class, did you declare `attr_accessible :body` maybe?

Comment: I did. Just to experiment, I tried removing it now, but that didn't work, either.

Answer (score 3):

You have fields_for @comment do |comment|
It should be:

```
fields_for :comments do |comment|
```

Then in the next line I would probably just use a string "Comment" for the label.